# Faye channel subcription and publishing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, private-pub

While experimenting with faye(private-pub in rails) i got a pretty basic doubt.Do we need to subscribe to a channel before publishing to that channel?

Please provide some resources for learning faye.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish messages to any arbitrary channel with Private Pub regardless of whether or not you've subscribed to it.  For instance, this example works just fine, without ever subscribing to anything:

```
PrivatePub.publish_to "some_random_channel", :data => "whatever"
```

Of course, the above code isn't useful at all - you can't receive that message without subscribing to that channel.

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye should you get starting or check out his references.